# Is it possible to color the cluster base on marker color?

Tags: google-maps, clustering, markers

So far, I've been able to generate the marker color base on query from my MySQL DB.

What I would like to attempt now is to cluster those markers with the dominant marker color.

For example, if I had marker1,2,3 with red color and 4,5 with green and marker6 with blue it would be generating a red cluster.

Logic for generating marker color:

```
            val[<?php echo $y;?>] = <?php echo $row1['amount'];?>;
            val[<?php echo $z;?>] = <?php echo $row2['amount'];?>;
            //compare
            if(val[<?php echo $y;?>] > val[<?php echo $z;?>])
            {
                image[<?php echo $x;?>]  = 'img/red.png';
            }           
            else if(val[<?php echo $y;?>]< val[<?php echo $z;?>])
            {
                image[<?php echo $x;?>]  = 'img/green.png';
            }
            else
            {
                image[<?php echo $x;?>]  = 'img/blue.png';

            }

            bounds.extend(location[<?php echo $x;?>]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: location[<?php echo $x;?>],
                icon:image[<?php echo $x;?>] 
            });
```

Any idea how should I approach this?